# I can't find the documentation for the layout &lt;fragment&gt; element

Tags: android, android-layout

Okay as everyone somehow seems to think I asked how to create a fragment in xml, let me make this absolutley clear, using the attributes shown in the page that I keep ending up on.

Are there any more attributes that can be used in the <fragment> xml element than these?

```
<fragment
    android:name=""
    android:id=""
    android:layout_weight=""
    android:layout_width=""
    android:layout_height=""/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I define a fragment's layout from XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454105/how-can-i-define-a-fragments-layout-from-xml)

Comment: @TheWanderer No it's not. I know how to create a UI through xml, but I want to find the detailed documentation for the fragment element, i.e. all attributes it supports, instead of having to go through trial and error, and I'd like to have a better understanding of the attributes added by android studio templates. The fragment's documentation pointed to in the question you linked does not do this.

Comment: Hmmm... asking for links to off site resources (e.g. documentation) is off topic here but you've been bravely searching a needle in a haystack. Is [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Adding) what you were looking for?

Comment: @0X0nosugar That's where I keep ending up, but I'm unclear if the attributes listed in the example shown on that page are all the attributes a fragment element can have, or if there are more.

Comment: atrributes with layout_ are directions to the layout itself of the widgets parent on how to place and size and configure the widget.  if you use android studio intelli sense will show you all the attributes of a fragment layout.

Comment: @yfdgvfasdasdas thanks, I've been pretty much relying on intelii sense to see what I can add, which is tedious, and relies on me being in android studio when I'm thinking of a design.

Comment: You have to specify a name and an id so the runtime knows which Fragment class to add and how to retrieve it from the back stack if necessary. IMO the key phrase hinting at possible other attributes is "you can specify layout properties for the fragment as if it were a view".

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yeah I was trying to get beyond working with hints and hunches, to more concrete facts. But TheWanderer has pointed me in the direction I wanted, so thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking under Android's [R.styleable documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable), I see a bunch of Fragment-related values:

```
android:fragmentAllowEnterTransitionOverlap
android:fragmentAllowReturnTransitionOverlap
android:fragmentEnterTransition
android:fragmentExitTransition
android:fragmentReenterTransition
android:fragmentReturnTransition
android:fragmentSharedElementEnterTransition
android:fragmentSharedElementReturnTransition
android:id
android:name
android:tag
```

Search for `Fragment_` and you'll see them. Unfortunately, I can't test them myself since I'm not near my IDE, but I think they are what you want.

Comment: Yep that's what I'm looking for, and didn't think to root under R.styleable. And of course a quick play with what you posted took me to a part of the Fragment documentation page which I kept missing that shows some more xml attributes. Case of couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thanks for the effort.